# Voice-based software for doing mathematics

Tags: soft-question, math-software

My uncle is a retired math professor. He has had some serious health issues in the past year, but he is still mentally sharp. For both fun and a distraction, he has been working on a textbook. However, I believe it is hard for him since he has trouble sitting at a desk and typing. Does anyone have any recommendations for good voice-to-text software that he could use? Latex and math formatting would be very helpful, obviously, although I could possibly help here.

Comment: https://support.texthelp.com/help/speech-input-commands-for-equatio#:~:text=Equatio%20allows%20the%20creation%20of,Record%20button%2C%20and%20begin%20speaking!

Comment: https://www.atwizard.org/voice-recognition-software-app-with

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RC2KZ2Ypw0